# How to create a component with hove in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a component that change when someone hover over it and let a `img` appear but I don't know whats wrong with my code, I'm not getting any error in the console but the `img` isn't showing. Here's my code:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

var Troll = {
  title: 'Why so serious?',
  src: '../imagenes/troll.png'
};

var Common = React.createClass({
  handleHover: function() {
    return (
    <img src={Troll.src} id='cara'/>
    );
  },
  render: function () {
    return (
    <div onMouseEnter={this.handleHover}>
      <h2>{Troll.title}</h2>
    </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <Common />,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only return JSX in a render function, but you are trying to do it in an event. Your `handleHover` method should contain just the logic to replace the markup that is being rendered, not the markup itself.

Answer (score 0):

The function `handleHover` must not return anything. It just need to show/hide the image.

Check this code:

```
class Avatar {
    render () {
    return (
        <div 
          className="avatar"
          onMouseOver={this.showImage.bind(this)}
          onMouseLeave={this.hideImage.bind(this)}>
        <figure ref="image">
            <img src={this.props.img}/>
        </figure>
        <p>John Doe</p>
      </div>
    )
  }

  showImage () {
    this.refs.image.classList.add('visible');
  }

  hideImage () {
    this.refs.image.classList.remove('visible');
  }
}

const node = document.getElementById('comp');
ReactDOM.render(
  <Avatar 
    img="http://www.material-ui.com/images/uxceo-128.jpg"
  />,
  node
);
```

We are just binding methods to `mouseover` and `mouseleave` events. The first method just show the image adding a CSS class, and the other method remove this class to hide it.

Click [here](https://jsfiddle.net/guzgarcia/j35scpbz/2/) to see this code running.

Comment: Try to avoid using refs wherever possible. This could be solved by using state instead.

Comment: Yeah, that's true. But, for this scenario I think it's neutral.

Comment: Additionally, string refs are likely to be deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other answers, you don't need to return anything. Try using React state to solve this instead:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

var Troll = {
  title: 'Why so serious?',
  src: '../imagenes/troll.png'
};

var Common = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      showTrollImage: false
    }
  },

  handleHover: function() {
    this.setState({ showTrollImage: true });
  },

  render: function () {
    var trollImage = null;

    if (this.state.showTrollImage) {
      trollImage = <div><img src={Troll.src} id="cara" /></div>;
    }

    return (
    <div onMouseEnter={this.handleHover}>
      <h2>{Troll.title}</h2>
      {trollImage}
    </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Common />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

And BTW, try to update your code to use ES6. [See here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) for an example of what modern React code looks like. I'll convert your `Common` component:

```
class Common extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showTrollImage: false,
    };
  }

  handleHover = () => {
    this.setState({ showTrollImage: true });
  };

  render() {
    let trollImage = null;

    if (this.state.showTrollImage) {
      trollImage = <div><img src={Troll.src} id="cara" /></div>;
    }

    return (
    <div onMouseEnter={this.handleHover}>
      <h2>{Troll.title}</h2>
      {trollImage}
    </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Note that this syntax:

```
handleHover = () => { };
```

is Babel [class property transformation](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/), and you'll need to install Babel stage 2 support in your project to use this.

Comment: Theres many things i still dont know ty for the help, is there some way that i can constantly practice code to learn more? its really hard try to create something alone and having problem that dont know how to solve just because im new in this

Comment: @GabrielMuñoz Sure! Definitely [start here](https://facebook.github.io/react/tutorial/tutorial.html) and then keep going through the official Facebook React website, looking at all the examples and references. That's probably the best starting point I can think of.